# Page reloads on completion of AJAX request using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I am trying to use a get request to run a python script and return a result using AJAX, Nodejs (using express) and Python-Shell (which runs a server side python script). I'm wanting this result to be returned into a div on my page.

The code does return a result from the python script back to into the web page (it flashes up for a second in the div), but then almost immediately, the page reloads.

**My client side JS Function (which is triggered through a button onclick event)**

```
function getResult() {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
    ResultCoords = encodeURI('oLat=' + document.getElementById('originLat').innerHTML + '&oLng=' + document.getElementById('originLng').innerHTML + '&dLat=' + document.getElementById('destLat').innerHTML + '&dLng=' + document.getElementById('destLng').innerHTML);
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/run?" + ResultCoords, false);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            string = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = string
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(ResultCoords)
}
```

**My server side script**

```
router.get('/run?*', (req, res) => {
    let options = {
        mode: 'text',
        pythonPath: 'my python path',
        pythonOptions: ['-u'],
        scriptPath: 'my script path',
        args: [req.query.oLat, req.query.oLng, req.query.dLat, req.query.dLng]
    };
    PythonShell.run('pythonScript.py', options, function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(results);
        const data = results;
        return res.send(data)
    });
});
```

I'm still very much a beginner with express, AJAX etc. so i'm open to any suggestions on improving the code if this isn't the right way to be doing these sort of things etc.

Thanks!